# Can I say "this water" or "that furniture"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

Can I say "this water" or "that furniture" ? If I can, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an English teacher but I speak English better than my native language so here goes. Using "this water" would simply be you referring to the water you are talking about, usually I think "this water" would be followed by some sort of adjective describing the water, for example:("is clear", "is murky", "is tasty").

The same goes for that furniture, of course pieces of furniture have names so you would be specifically pointing out a piece of furniture here. You would also be describing it and using an adjective on it based on what you see/think about it, for example: ("is old", "is broken", "is big").

And yes you can say "this water" and "this furniture", however I think it should be followed up with an adjective, otherwise it would not make sense to simply say "this water" or "this furniture" on it's own.

Comment: Suppose you want to rent an apartment. When you enter an apartment, you see the furniture, for example, two sofas, a table, some chairs, and a bookcase. You said, "this furniture is old". Do you mean all the furniture or only a piece of furniture?

Comment: I believe you would be referring to it all, you would be making a generalisation. Unless you don't specifically indicate one in some way. So yes, I believe so.

Comment: Íf you mean a piece of furniture, you say either "that piece of furniture" or "that sofa", "table", etc.